# PHP Error, class not found

Tags: php

I'm getting the following output on my page when I go to Test.php:

```
    longitude = $long; 
    $this->latitude = $lat; 
} 

public function getgeo(){ 
    require_once('lib/mapbox/MapBox.php'); 
    $request = new MapBox('redacted'); 
    $request = $request->reverseGeocode($this->longitude,$this->latitude); 
    $request = explode(', ',$request[0]['place_name']); 
    if(count($request)>3){ 
        array_shift($request); 
        array_splice($request,2,1); 
    }
    $return = array($request[0],$request[2]); 
} 
} 
?>
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'ReverseGeo' not found in /var/www/html/api.redacted.com/public_html/test.php:8 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/api.redacted.com/public_html/test.php on line 8

**Test.php**

```
<?php
require_once(__dir__ . '/classes/reversegeo.php');

$long = '-73.988909';
$lat = '40.733122';

$reversegeo = new ReverseGeo($long, $lat);
$return = $reversegeo->getgeo();

var_dump($return);

?>
```

**classes/reversegeo.php**

```
Class ReverseGeo{

protected $longitude;
protected $latitude;

public function __construct($long, $lat){
    $this->longitude = $long;
    $this->latitude = $lat;
}

public function getgeo(){
    require_once('lib/mapbox/MapBox.php');
    $request = new MapBox('redacted');
    $request = $request->reverseGeocode($this->longitude,$this->latitude);

    $request = explode(', ',$request[0]['place_name']);

    if(count($request)>3){
        array_shift($request);
        array_splice($request,2,1);
    }

    $return = array($request[0],$request[2]);
}
}
```

I've confirmed that directories are all correct, file names are correct, etc. and I'm not sure whats going on with this.

Comment: If you inspect the page, does it show the full code in the source? [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page)

Comment: It does show the full code in the source.

Comment: do a `var_dump(__dir__)` to see what you get

Comment: string(48) "/var/www/html/api.redacted.com/public_html"

Comment: so is `reversegeo.php` located on `/var/www/html/api.redacted.com/public_html/reversegeo.php` ?

Comment: /var/www/html/api.redacted.com/public_html/classes/reversegeo.php

Comment: ah right.. i forgot 'classes' .. hmm..

Comment: alter the require_once to just everything inside the quotes minus the first / before classes and see if that helps. (sorry put include instead of require_once)

Comment: @Chris no change unfortunately.

Comment: try an include instead of a require_once

include "path/to/classfile.php";

Comment: tried include, require, and require_once. Still the same issue :/

Comment: have you checked the permissions of the class file? 755 or 644 should be sufficient. If thats all correct, require_once ('enter the full path');

Comment: The files are all 644; 755 doesn't change anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133128/discussion-between-chris-and-kaylined).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per our discussion in chat, as your php does not support the short opening tag you need to use the full opener. The short tag is the reason that your php source code gets sent directly to the browser and not to the php engine.

You can configure your php settings to allow the short opening tag but its not recommended for portability reasons.

```
<? should be changed to <?php
```

As a side note later versions of php no longer need the closing tag at the end of the file so that can be removed if your php supports it.